# Find the number of numbers from range 0 to (10^n)-1 in which 13 is not present

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy

How do I approach this problem other than using brute force?
Example: if n=4, then range is (0,9999) and numbers like 5130 should not be present because it has '13' in it.

Comment: How big would your result set be? Surely greater than N/2.. think about it

Comment: Result should be an integer, as you have to find the number of numbers.

Comment: The answer is dynamic programming. Since you have tagged the question as "dynamic-programming" you probably already knew that (if not, good guess). Did you get stuck somewhere when you tried to apply dynamic programming? If so, perhaps you could explain what you tried.

Comment: This is math/combinatorics question. Check [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle). Number of n digit numbers having k 13's is (probably :-)  (n-k-1 binomial k-1)*10^(n-2*k) + (n-k-1 binomial k)*9*10^(n-2*k-1). First summand is when 13 is on first place, and second when first two digits are not 13.